# How can I use AJAX to retrieve multiple data from a PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm working on a project where I have an HTML file with 2 different divs: "product" and "price". The text inside these divs must come from a row into a database. I can easily access these text values with a php file. I'm also able to get just **one** of them using AJAX and I can put it inside one of the divs. The problem is I don't know **how I can get both product and price and put them inside the divs**. I've found some very similar questions but none of the answers have worked for me.

Here is the JS code that I have:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "url to the php file",             
    dataType: "html",                
    success: function(response){                    
        $("#product").html(response);
    }
});
```

Here is the php (the columns I have are just id, product and price):

```
mysqli_query($link, $query);
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = 1";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "{$row['product']}";
    }
}
```

**As I said, the code above works, but only for "product". I want to get both "product" and "price".** I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: In the above code you're only echoing the `$row['product']` value from the database.  Presumably the price is in a *different* column?  Why not echo *both* values?

Comment: Why don't you simply `echo "{$row['price']}"` ?

Comment: What are the columns that are used in the product? Does it contain price?

Comment: *"how I can get both product and price and put them inside the divs"* - what div's? Post your HTML for this.

Comment: and why do you have this on the first line? `mysqli_query($link, $query);`

Comment: *"how I can get both product and price"* - Umm... add the associated row in the echo? You're just using `$row['product']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JSON. Here is a simple example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "url to the php file",             
    dataType: "html",                
    success: function(response){                    
        $("#name").html(response.name);
        $("#shoes").html(response.large);           
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

And then in the PHP to return back JSON use this approach:

```
$array = array('name' => 'Bob', 'shoes' => 'large');
echo json_encode($array);
```

You can amend my PHP so you return back whatever you query from your database.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I did exactly what you suggested and now it works perfectly!